# overwriting default $PATH

Tags: debian, bash, login, raspbian, profile

I am trying to lock down regular users on a Raspbian installation. I'll be using `rbash` for that.

I want to edit the PATH file so that only `~/bin` files can be executed.

I've stripped `$PATH` from `/etc/profile/`:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH=""
fi
export PATH
```

I've stripped `$PATH` from `/etc/login.defs`:

```
# cat /etc/login.defs | grep PATH=
ENV_SUPATH      PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH        PATH=""
```

The `/etc/environment` file is empty:

```
~ # cat /etc/environment
~ #
```

The local user's `.profile` file contains only the following:

```
$ cat .profile
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin"
fi
```

That works fine when running `ssh user@host`:

```
$ free
-rbash: free: command not found
$ uname
-rbash: uname: command not found
$ echo $PATH
/home/user/bin
```

However, when running `ssh -t user@host bash --noprofile` `.profile` is not executed, and I still get access to a fully working $PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
$ uname
Linux
```

What am I missing here? Where else is the `$PATH` file defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's set by sshd itself:

```
$ strings /usr/sbin/sshd | grep games
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

In `man ssh` under `ENVIRONMENT` it says:

```
 ssh will normally set the following environment variables:
 (...)
 PATH                  Set to the default PATH, as specified when compiling ssh.
```

To prevent sshd from setting PATH to the default value set

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set a new value of PATH in
~/.ssh/environment, for example

```
PATH=~/bin
```

And restart SSH service:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

BTW, you can get all of this information from `man sshd_config`.

Comment: Is there a way for changing this without recompiling SSH?

Comment: @Tuinslak: see edited answer